# Python Spyder start up error No Qt application plug could be initialized

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I just installed anaconda, along with a bunch of extra packages outside the ones that come with the installation.  Now, Spyder won't start, and I get the error "The application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be intitialized.  Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

Well, reinstalling Spyder did nothing.  There are other solutions posted on the internet, such as here, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/this-application-failed-to-start-because-no-qt/e5b31106-84a1-4196-92f3-a1ee633f68b0, don't work.

These solutions tell you to search for the pyqt5_tools folder, but I don't have one as far as I can tell, as windows never finds it.  What's going on here?  Any help on this would be great.  This is literally the 4th time I've installed anaconda, and every time I do, some other problems arise.  Does anyone else have this many issues with Anaconda?

Comment: Try installing `pyqt5` using pip. I've seen this error but not in this specific context, what fixed it for me was making sure Python can access some dlls for Qt (which are included in `pyqt5`).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.  It seems like my pycharm installation is messing with this particular package.